# How to get list of git tags, which contain a specific file?

Tags: git

Is there a way I can get list of git tags, which contain a specific file?

Comment: Oh, you should have started your question with that.

Comment: The answers should work in bash that you get with MSysGit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply pipe to xargs and check each tag:

```
git tag | xargs -i{} bash -c 'git ls-tree -r {} | grep yourfile >/dev/null && echo {}'
```

Comment: Thanks Adam. It seems like working. One small correction, `xargs -i`. It says `Invalid option -- I`.

Answer (score 5):

This is what I did to get the list of tags which contain the specific file:

1) Get the first commit id which introduces the file. You can use git log command.

```
git log -- <path/to/filename>
```

2) List the tags, which contain the commit id.

```
git tag --contains <CommitId>
```

This may be wrong. So, I'll wait for other's answers. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
git for-each-ref 'refs/tags/*' | while read rev type name
do
  [ -n "$(git ls-tree $rev -- "$filename")" ] && echo $name
done | sed -e 's/^refs\/tags\///'
```

Comment: Besides the output format, is there any difference between the lists of items returned by `git for-each-ref refs/tags` and `git tag -l`?

Comment: I imagine not, provided that the repository is in good order and doesn't have branch/tag name collisions or such.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know how to do it only with git, but here's the result of my struggles with bash:

```
for tag in `git tag -l`; do [ -n "`git ls-tree $tag path/to/file`" ] && echo $tag; done
```

Comment: That's basically how I'd do it too. Although note you can give the file path to `git ls-tree` directly, which seems a bit nicer.

Comment: Is this shell script? I'm using windows.

Comment: It's a bash script and it won't work in `cmd`. Your note about Windows came too late.